# SQL - simple model - issue

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Every single car or truck can have ***multiple*** packages. I have to make a relationships with packages.

#### Question: Is the only way out to have another table that can handle relationships?

I need the most effective way.

**EDIT**: I know that in PostgreSQL are Arrays. But elements in Array can not have a foreign key.

### Tables:

Table I. - **Cars**

Id | Name

Table II. - **Trucks**

Id | Name | Color

// ... in future Airplanes, Trains ...

Table III. - **Packages**

Id | Name

***Table IV. - for relationships***

Id | Type | PackageId

-------- or --------

***Table IV.***

Id | CarId | PackageId

and

***Table V.***

Id | TruckId | PackageId

Comment: You can do it either way. A link table for trucks and a separate linke table for cars may be easier to manage, but obviously if you had planes, trains, and bicycles too then you might want to rethink that design.

Comment: 1) Can a single package represented by `packageId` be associated with both a `carId` and a `truckId`? If not, then `packageId` would be unique in the association table IV. How would you represent uniqueness with two tables IV and V (ref. integrity)? 2) What is your key for `relationships IV`? Only `id`? Then to which of the two tables I and II do you write your (two? partial?) foreign key constraint to? Or is it `(id, type)`? And then the FK goes to? The question is more, whether you have something common like `vehicleId, name` for all vehicles and you want to associate them together or not...

Comment: You can try something like `vehicles (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, type TEXT NOT NULL)` and then extend them individually. For example `trucks (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES vehicles, color TEXT NOT NULL)`. And still have a `many-to-many` or `many-to-one` relationship with the `packages (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, cargo TEXT NOT NULL)` table with `vehicles_packages (vehicle_id INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES vehicles (id), package_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES packages (id), PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_id, package_id))`. Is that an idea?

Comment: You can also consider PostgreSQL's object relational inheritance for tables. Read the documentation for that. AFAIR neither MySQL nor MariaDB offer that, though (and your question is tagged with both RDBMS).